# URL Routing / MapRequestHandler error for HTML page in IIS

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, web-config, iis-7.5, url-routing

In my localhost, I cannot setup working environment. I copied web.config from staging where everything is ok. I get error 404 for html page.

```
Module IIS Web Core
Notification    MapRequestHandler
Handler StaticFile
Error Code  0x80070002
```

I added following in web.config from [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd347546.aspx) article which is not present in Staging and still works but I added in my localhost with no success :

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
   <remove name="ScriptModule" />
   <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
   <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
</modules>
<handlers accessPolicy="Read, Execute, Script">
   <add name="UrlRoutingHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="UrlRouting.axd" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
</handlers>
```

Site has CMS and html pages are stored in DB, no physical HTML page exists. But I thought following should do job for redirecting:

```
<httpErrors>
   <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
   <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/_redirect.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

What else can I do here to run my html page? Any help is much appriciated!